# Google Maps InfoWindow Width Stuck at 707px

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Angular Google Maps to integrate Maps in my website.

I have a div inside my infowindow that has a width and height set, this works fine until I set it bigger than 707px, then it doesn't size any bigger.

I have my div set at 900px but that's not working, any help?

[image]

Comment: what is the width of your entire map div?

Comment: about 1900px, it's 100% width and height

Comment: Do you have any aspect ratio set? In general if you could show your CSS its more helpful.

Comment: hey, all my code including css is here: https://github.com/bernhardmostrey/TriplerBeta

Comment: Try using position property as fixed (rather than relative) for the info window and pad it accordingly.